# Line integral over triangle using stokes theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

Let C be the triangle with vertices $(5, 0, 0)$, $(0, 5, 0)$ and $(0, 0, 2)$. I want to find the line integral $$\oint_C \frac{4}{25}xydx+\frac{2}{5}yzdy+1xzdz \,$$ where $C$ is the curve oriented clockwise as seen from the point $(5, 5, 5)$.

I found the projection of my triangle in the $xy$-plane to be limited by
$$0\leq x \leq 5$$ and 
$$0 \leq y \leq 5-x$$

I also found $curl F$ = $[-\frac{2}{5}y, -z, -\frac{4}{25}x]$.
The plane intersecting the three points is $2x+2y+5z-10=f(x,y,z)$ and thus $\nabla f = [2, 2, 5]$

Substituting $-z$ where $z=-\frac{2}{5}(x+y-5)$ and taking the dot product 
$curl F \cdot \nabla f$ I am left with $-4$ and $$ \int_{0}^{5}\int_{0}^{5-x}  -4 dy dx = -50$$ but this is not the correct answer. What have I done wrong?

Comment: How do you know that's not the correct answer? What is the correct one, then?

Comment: Three things wrong, offhand. You need a *unit* normal, so $\nabla f$ needs to be normalized. And then you need to think about orientation. In fact, because of the clockwise orientation, you'll need the *negative* for the normal. Also, did you account for the tilt of the plane when you turned your surface integral into a double integral? I'm getting the answer $10$.

Comment: 10 is the correct answer, thank you Shifrin. You're right about normalizing the vector, this gives me $$[\frac{2}{\sqrt{33}}, \frac{2}{\sqrt{33}}, \frac{5}{\sqrt{33}}]$$. Dotting this with $curl F$ and integrating along the same boundaries, I don't get 10 however. What do you mean by accounting for the tilt of the plane? Are my boundaries incorrect? Thank you for the assistance

Comment: Remember that you have a "fudge factor" that comes from parametrizing the plane. Since you are representing the plane as the graph of $z=g(x,y)$, the fudge factor will be $\sqrt{1+(\partial g/\partial x)^2 + (\partial g/\partial y)^2}$. Your surface does, in fact, project to the triangle over which you've done the double integral, so that part is fine.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!